# How to add a new project as a commit instead of an old one and not lose history?

Tags: git, spring-boot, intellij-idea, repository

I use Intellij to upload projects on Github, is it possible to upload a new project as an old commit? Of course, I don't want to lose the history of the old project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

All you have to do is delete all files of old project and copy paste the files of new project inside the project folder. I hope you don't have to change this project folder name. But make sure you don't delete `.git` folder inside your project folder. It's a hidden folder. Rest all you can delete.

After that just commit this big change and a new project will be pushed over the old project in the repository as a commit.

I hope you know how to commit.

Comment: I did that, but when I want compile my app I see this:

[IMG](https://i.imgur.com/1mvXfQy.jpg)

Shouldn't I do something more?

Comment: Now works, package name must be the same, thanku you, I didn't know that .git folder is hidden :)